# unable to display clock in output

Tags: c

To produce millisecond using clock function after strcat but it simply crash, what could be the problem?

```
FREObject result = 0;

uint32_t len = -1;
const uint8_t *str = 0;
char *temp = "Millisecond: ";
uint8_t *strAll;

clock_t curtime = clock();

double *asc = (double *) curtime;  //Using double datatype?

if(FREGetObjectAsUTF8(argv[0], &len, &str) == FRE_OK) {

  strAll = (char *)malloc(strlen(temp) + strlen(str) + 1 + strlen(asc) + 1);
  strcpy(strAll,temp);
  strcat(strAll,str);
  strcat(strAll," ");
  strcat(strAll,(char *)asc);  //Is this correct?
}

FRENewObjectFromUTF8(strlen((const char *)strAll)+1, (const uint8_t *)strAll, &result);         

return result;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assignment to `asc` is extremely dubious:

```
double *asc = (double *) curtime;  //Using double datatype?
```

You can measure the difference between two `clock()` values, to determine the processor time used.

You might get more nearly successful results with:

```
double asc = curtime;
```

The `strlen()` operation is undefined - under either definition of `asc`:

```
strAll = (char *)malloc(strlen(temp) + strlen(str) + 1 + strlen(asc) + 1);
```

Then the `strcat()` operation is going fail horribly; you have to convert the `double` to a string before you can concatenate the string to another.

```
strcat(strAll,(char *)asc);  //Is this correct?
```

So, you have a lot of work to do.  You need to decide whether `clock()` is the right system call.  If it is, you have to fix the sizing and the conversion of `asc` or `curtime` to a string before you concatenate it to the result.

Comment: Also, I think `clock_t` is a long integer rather than a double.

Comment: thx, seem like a lot to work on double to string, I don't find any string function on C? So will have to use Array?

Comment: @JamesONG to convert a `double` (or a `long`) to a string in C, I would recommend [`sprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf).

Comment: @JamesONG: You need to have *strings* in C `NUL` terminated. `malloc` is not assured to 0 fill, you can use `calloc` instead. Dont typecast the return value of `malloc` or `calloc` if your code is in C. And as Timothy Jones has suggested you can make use of `sprintf` or `snprintf` instead of `strcpy` & `strcat` calls in your current case.

Answer (score 2):

Jonathan Leffler's answer outlines a number of things you will need to sort out before your code will work. If you haven't already, you should give him an upvote :)

---

In your current code, the cast to `(char*)` in your code tells the compiler to treat the memory where `asc` is stored as a `char*`, but it won't do the conversion to string for you.
In order to convert a `double` to a string, have a look at [`sprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf). I would replace the strcat lines with this:

```
sprintf(strAll,"%s%s %f",temp,str,asc);
```

Note that you would first need to make sure that `strAll` is big enough to contain the resulting string. This could be a little bit tricky for a `double`. However, I don't really think you have a `double` - `clock_t` is probably a `long`, which means you could do this:

```
long asc = (long) curtime;

...

strAll = malloc(strlen(temp) + strlen(str) + 1 + (asc/10 +1) + 1);
sprintf(strAll,"%s%s %ld",temp,str,asc);
```

Warning: `asc/10 +1` only tells you how many characters you need to allocate for a non-negative number. Since clock is documented to return negative in error cases, you should first check for that.

Note that I also removed the cast to `char*` [since it can cause problems in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) (thanks to an anonymous commenter).

Also: Currently the result of malloc isn't checked for errors - on error, it will return `NULL`, which will break attempts to use `strAll`. Consequently, it's a good idea to make sure it isn't `NULL` before trying to use it.

Comment: You need to `NUL` terminate the *string*. `malloc` is not assured to 0 fill the memory, you are better off with `calloc` instead. It is better not to typecast the return value of `malloc` or `calloc`

Comment: Doesn't `sprintf` put null in? Or am I missing something else?

Comment: Why do you say it's not good to cast the result of `malloc`?

Comment: I found [this question about malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) - I'll update the answer :)

Comment: You are right about `sprintf` adding `NUL` character. In this case there is no problem. About `malloc`, well have found the question!

Comment: Hi, how do I get the info that asc/10 is only for non-negative number?